# Error While Deploying Django with Jenkins

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, jenkins, deployment

I have created a new job in Jenkins. After build getting an error on the console output.

```
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /var/www/project/venv/bin/python3
Not overwriting existing python script /var/www/project/venv/bin/python (you must use /var/www/project/venv/bin/python3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2327, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 712, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 926, in create_environment
    install_distutils(home_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1482, in install_distutils
    mkdir(distutils_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 323, in mkdir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/www/project/venv/lib64/python3.6/distutils'
Running virtualenv with interpreter /bin/python3
```

Jenkins Exec Commands:

```
rm -rf /var/www/project/*.*
touch /var/www/project/debug.log
cp -rf  /home/centos/build/*  /var/www/project/
cd /var/www/project

virtualenv -p python3 venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt

sudo ln -sf  /opt/project/.env /var/www/project/mysite/
python3 mysite/manage.py collectstatic  --noinput
python3 mysite/manage.py makemigrations  --noinput
python3 mysite/manage.py migrate --noinput

sudo chown -R centos.centos /var/www/project/*

sudo /usr/sbin/service httpd restart
```

Comment: Can you please provide the contents of your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: It looks like when you run `virtualenv` it runs as python2. Maybe you need to do something like `python3 -m virtualenv -p python3 venv` so that `virtualenv` will be run by python3.